# $X_n$ have distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, a^n)$, where $a > 0$. Determine the probability that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ converges.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

The variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, (...)$ are independent. $X_n$ have a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, a^n)$, where $a > 0$. Determine the probability that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$$

converges.

I did similar things proving that series described like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_n}{n}$ converge almost surely. I did that usually using strong law of large numbers. I don't know if the same logic could be applied here as well.

Comment: The answer is going to be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) should help you. Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem)

Comment: What do you mean by "$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_n}{n}$ converges almost surely"?  If $a\le 1$ I can see it converges in distribution, but I am not so sure for $a>1$

Comment: Agreed, if $a>1,$ I'm not sure we can even say $\frac{X_n}n\to 0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ , then $S_{n}$ has Normal distribution.

So in particular for $a\geq 1$, you have that $Var(S_{n})\to \infty$ . So you cannot even have convergence in distribution as the characteristic function $\exp(-\frac{t Var(S_{n})}{2})\to 0$ which cannot be a characteristic function for any random variable.

> Almost sure convergence/Convergence in Probability would have implied convergence in distribution of $S_{n}$ to some random variable $X$.

For $a<1$, you have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Var(X_{k})<\infty$ which in particular by Khintchine-Kolmogorov Theorem, gives you almost sure convergence of $S_{n}$ to some random variable $X$.

> A quick justification for the proof is that the sum of variances
> being finite, implies $S_{n}$ is Cauchy in $L^{2}$ sense. Thus $S_{n}$
> is an uniformly integrable Martingale which by Martingale convergence
> theorem, converges almost surely and in $L^1$ to some integrable
> random variable $X$. Otherwise, a Theorem due to Levy gives that for
> independent $X_{k}$'s, $S_{n}$ being Cauchy in Probability(which follows from $S_{n}$ being Cauchy in $L^{2}$) is both
> necessary and sufficient for $S_{n}$ to be almost surely Cauchy. This
> provides another proof of Khintchine Kolmogorov Theorem.

Now, as to what the limiting distribution is, again, you figure out that $Var(S_{n})\to\frac{a}{1-a}$. Hence the sequence of characteristic functions $\exp(\frac{-t\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}}{2})\to \exp(\frac{-ta}{2(1-a)})$ which is the c.f. of a $N(0,\frac{a}{1-a})$ variate.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. So in the case of $a \leq 1$ we have that the necesary condition fails to work for even convergence in distribution, right? If we had that characteristic function goes to some constant we would have convergence in distribution and in probability, right? But that still wouldn't be almost sure convergence. @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: You mean $a\geq 1$.  Well, you see that the characteristic functions converge to $0$ which is not a valid characteristic function for any random variable(for example $\phi(0)=1$ for any random variable). So, in particular you don't have convergence in distribution. So if in fact, $S_{n}$ converged almost surely or in Probability to some random variable $X$, then it would also converge in distribution to $X$ (as those implies convergence in distribution) . But this is obviously a contradiction as $S_{n}$ does NOT converge in distribution to any random variable. @mathman12

Comment: ok. Now I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_N = \sum_{n = 1}^N X_n$. From the independence of the $X_i$'s, $S_N \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_N^2)$ with $\sigma_N^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^N a^n$.

Firstly, let us show that the probability that $\sum_n X_n$ diverges is $1$ if $a \geqslant 1$. Let $M > 0$.
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \lvert S_N \rvert < M \right) = \varphi \left( \frac{M}{\sigma_N} \right) - \varphi \left( -\frac{M}{\sigma_N} \right)
$$
where $\varphi$ is the normal cumulative distribution function. If $a \geqslant 1$, $\sigma_N \to +\infty$ as $N \to +\infty$. Hence, $\mathbb{P} \left( \lvert S_N \rvert < M \right) \to 0$ as $N \to +\infty$.

Then, if $0 < a < 1$, let $S_\infty \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{a}{1 - a})$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.
$$
\mathbb{P}(\lvert S_N - S_\infty \rvert < \varepsilon) = \varphi \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\sigma_N^2 - \frac{a}{1 - a}}} \right) - \varphi \left( -\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\sigma_N^2 - \frac{a}{1 - a}}} \right)
$$
since $S_N - S_\infty \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_N^2 - \frac{a}{1 - a})$. As $N \to +\infty$, $\sigma_N^2 \to \frac{a}{1 - a}$ therefore,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\lvert S_N - S_\infty \rvert < \varepsilon) \xrightarrow[N \to +\infty]{} 1
$$
and we have showed the convergence in probability of $S_N$ to $S_\infty$. To conclude, the probability that $\sum_n X_n$ converges — i.e., the probability that $S_\infty$ is finite — is $1$.

Comment: Your argument is for convergence in probability and not almost surely!

Comment: @hugo You can conclude almost sure convergence but that would require you to prove that $S_{n}$ being Cauchy in Probability implies and is implied by $S_{n}$ being Cauchy almost surely (where $S_{n}$ denotes sum of **independent** random variables). That is a theorem due to Levy. Otherwise, an easier method (which requires knowledge of Martingales) is that $S_{n}$ being $L^{2}$ bounded and hence uniformly integrable martingale is enough for a random variable $X$ to exists such that $S_{n}$ converges in $L^{1}$ and a.s. to $X$ due to Martingale convergence theorem.

Comment: Why would you need almost sure convergence?

Comment: @hugo Because the question asks for the **probability** of convergence of $S_{N}$ . It's one thing to state that due to Kolmogorov's zero-one law that it will be $0$ or $1$ , but still, one has to show that for $a<1$, you do have it is $1$ and for $a\geq 1$ , the probability is $0$.

Comment: From convergence in Probability, you cannot conclude that directly and justification has to be given as to why you do have almost sure convergence.